# SQL query in php with input from html dropdown

Tags: php, html, sql, web

Ok so what I'm trying to do is make a query evaluation tool for a project. I get the user input as a php variable and use it in my query, so it's like the user is submitting the query. I am using mysqli

I'm currently doing this with my my query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `idk` where  `alias` = '".$s."'";
```

I get the values from the form below

```
$s = $_GET['val'];
```

```
<select name="selector" id = "selector">
        <option value="">Select a criteria:</option>
        <option value="0">id</option>
        <option value="1">name</option>
        <option value="2">email</option>
        <option value="3">alias</option>
        <option value="4">position</option>
```

I'm wondering if I can add user input for the where clause condition(=,!=) and get it like i get the value for the column instead of hard coding it.

Keep in mind that this is for a uni project and no one is going to use it or delete my database, but any security suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Learn to use parameterized queries first.

Comment: what is the question

Comment: if i can use a php variable instead of the actual = or LIKE

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're asking or trying to do here. Are you asking if you can use a PHP variable to form a `where` condition in your query? If so, how does the provided `select` affect it? What is the structure of the table? In general, what is supposed to happen when a user selects one of the options and submits the form?

Comment: @El_Vanja i edited the question, sorry for being unclear. I am really new to this and it confuses me a lot. I am sorry if im asking the wrong questions or in a weird way. any help would be greatly appreciated. Yes im trying to get the user to submit the where clause condition and im wondering if i can make the whole where clause using user input

Comment: I'm still not sure I fully understand what you need. You want the user to control "equal", "not equal", "greater than" and so on?

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful to know if you're using `mysqli` or `PDO` for querying.

Comment: @El_Vanja yes that is what i want to do. also im using mysqli

Comment: I'd suggest you edit that additional info into the question, so that anyone that comes across it in the future can get a clearer picture.

Comment: @El_Vanja i think the question looks better now, edited in what you suggested. Any idea of how to solve the problem though?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest possible answer: yes. You can control everything. All you need to achieve this is add another choice element into your form that will let the user control the way values are compared. I'll use a simplified example.

If you have an input for the user's value:

```html
<input type="number" name="age" value="" />
```

add a choice field before it:

```html
<select name="age_comparison">
    <option value="equal">equal to</option>
    <option value="not_equal">not equal to</option>
    <option value="less_than">less than</option>
    <option value="greater_than">greater than</option>
</select>
<input type="number" name="age" value="" />
```

> *Note*: the position isn't relevant for handling - at all. I just think it's a better user experience if users read your page just like they would a piece of text in real life. Meaning that when input comes later it will read as "age greater than X", which reads better than "age X, greater than", if you put the input first.
>
> For the same reason (better user experience), I tend to label the options with something that reads more like a human, hence "equal to" instead of just "equal". But I omitted it from the option values since it doesn't add any valuable information to the code ("equal" tells the whole story as a parameter value).

Then, after your form is submitted, you can detect your user's choice and build the query string accordingly:

```php
if (isset($_GET['age'])) {
    $age = $_GET['age'];
}
if (isset($_GET['age_comparison'])) {
    switch ($_GET['age_comparison']) {
        case 'equal':
            $ageComparison = '=';
            break;
        case 'not_equal':
            $ageComparison = '!=';
            break;
        case 'less_than':
            $ageComparison = '<';
            break;
        case 'greater_than':
            $ageComparison = '>';
            break;
    }
}
// if we have all the parameters, we can query the database
if (isset($age) && isset($ageComparison)) {
    // the following line is very unsafe - we'll be on that in a minute
    $queryString = 'SELECT * FROM students WHERE age '.$ageComparison.$age;
    ...
```

> *Note*: I used `$_GET` because you used it in your question. If you're going to have multiple parameters in your form, I suggest you rather use the `post` method and avoid having a whole bunch of parameters added to the url of your page. Your form values will be under the same keys, only in the `$_POST` variable. Plus, when you use `post`, it's enough to detect if the name of the submit is set - if it is, the rest of the inputs from the same form is guaranteed to be present as well. With `get` you have to check every parameter individually.

So there you have it. A query with variable comparison operators.

**BUT**

We're not done yet. There are some bad practices to shed away and some good practices to pick up on the way.

First and foremost, never build queries by directly inserting parameters:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `idk` where  `alias` = '".$s."'";
```

That makes you wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Prepared statements have built-in protection mechanisms and also take care of all your quoting needs (meaning you don't have to manually put uote marks around parameters that are strings). So you do it like this:

```php
// the question mark means we'll be adding a parameter in that position
$queryString = 'SELECT * FROM students WHERE age '.$ageComparison.' ?';
// here I assume you have mysqli statement ready
// you can see an example about creating one in the link about prepared statements
$statement->prepare($queryString);
$statement->bindParam('i', $age);
```

You might say "But *wait a minute*! You just added the comparison operator *directly*! Isn't that dangerous?" - no, because it didn't come directly from the user. We decided its value in the switch statement, meaning we took user's input (which might be compromised) and turned it into a value that **we control**. The user can't decide what comes out of the switch statement, we can. Hence, it's safe to directly concatenate it into the query string because we know we've defined some safe values.

Speaking of the switch statement, there's an improvement to be made there, too. What if we add another option in the `select`, but we forget to add it in the switch statement? Or a malicious user compromises the value of the option being sent? We will end up with an error, since then no cases in the switch will be matched (a case for a value outside of the 4 we put there is not defined) and thus the variable `$ageComparison` will never be created and we'll never execute the query, because our if condition will fail. So how do we fix it? We add a default case (default executes when none of the cases are matched):

```php
// remainder of statement cut for length
    ...
    case 'greater_than':
        $queryComparison = '>';
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception('Unsupported value for age comparison: '.$ageComparison);
}
```

Exceptions halt execution when not handled (the proper term is *caught*), but I'll leave it to you if you wish to explore that topic on your own (seems a bit much for a beginner, plus there's quite a bit of text here already).

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much for taking the time to do this. Also thank you for explaining prepared statements. I appreciate this a lot it really helps

Comment: This works fine for my ID but not for stuff like name. Do I have to modify things to work with strings?

Comment: Yes, when you're binding a parameter, you have to tell the function what the type is. Whenever you're unsure about something, your first step is to consult the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).